# How to show only filenames with "git status"?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-status, git-ls-files

How do I show only filenames for all modified files in my repository?  `git status` adds additional output, e.g.,

```sh
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
    modified:   my-file (modified content)
```

How do I get:

```sh
$ git status --name-only   # --name-only is not a valid option; what do I use instead?
my-file
```

Comment: There isn't one. But `git status` is just one of many Git tools. If you want different results, use different tools, such as `git diff --name-only`. (I see this was a self-answer, and have upvoted your answer, since it's, well, the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

There's an output option which does pretty much what you asked.

Only paths, with a letter to indicate A(dded), (M)odified, and so on.

```
git status -s [-b]
```

Comment: That's close @RomainValeri, but I don't want the prefixed letters ( (A)dded, (M)odified, ...).  I know I could strip those off using something like `sed`, but am wondering if there's a way to do it without that.  See my answer using "git diff".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `git status`, use `git diff`, e.g.,

```sh
$ # Show modified, unstaged files, and only the filenames
$ git diff --name-only --diff-filter=u
my-file

$ # Show modified, staged/cached files, and only the filenames
$ git diff --name-only --diff-filter=u --cached
my-staged-file
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't take into account staged files. If you wanted only *unstaged* files, it should have been in the question.

Comment: @RomainValeri I have now updated the answer to how to take into account staged/cached files with the `--cached` option